# cannot expand partition

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to expand `/dev/xvda1` to 25Gb does anyone know how to do that.

```
[ec2-user@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XX~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.8G   47M 100% /
tmpfs                 849M     0  849M   0% /dev/shm


[ec2-user@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XX~]$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda1 202:1    0   25G  0 disk /
xvda3 202:3    0  896M  0 disk
```

When I try `umount:sudo umount /`

it says that the

> device is busy. (In some cases useful info about processes that use
>   the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```

Comment: You should add some explanation why this answers the question.